# Why are loop0 and ram1 getting mixed up?

Tags: block-device

I've been rolling my own "minimal" linux system under WMware based on the 5.15.x kernel. I don't use an initramfs but do include support for the default max 16 ramdrives in the kernel build config. Everything works great. For fun I decided to mount a ramdisk on `/tmp` so I did

```
mknod /dev/ram1 b 1 1 
mkfs.ext2 /dev/ram1 4096
mount -t ext2 /dev/ram1 /tmp
```

It seems fine, and mount shows that `/dev/ram1` is mounted on `/tmp`, but
`df` thinks `/dev/loop0` is mounted on `/tmp`. I use `loop0` for another purpose which is now broken, so there is some confusion in the system between loop0 and ram1. I wonder why? `loop0` has device numbers `7,0` and `ram1` has numbers `1,1`.

Comment: output of df as well as /proc/mounts?

Comment: You're rolling your own. So have you inadvertently got ram and loop sharing the same device major number? Have you got /dev/ram* and /dev/loop* device nodes incorrect?

Comment: I deleted /dev/ram1 and recreated and now all is well. I think I had made it a character device rather than block. Maybe in that situation the first available block device gets recruited to buffer writes? Anyway thx 4 comments.